# Ubuntu 10.10 on a dell inspiron 6000

Tags: inspiron

According to my service tag I have a

```
 64MB, I6000, M22 Surface Mount Graphics card
```

when i first installed Ubuntu the tool bars were all distorted.  I updated to 10.10 (after many attempts where it would get stuck half way through the installation) and now only the tool bars show up. Anything on the main section of the screen shows up black.I can try clicking around aimlessly and the windows I open are there i just can't see them.Any ideas?

Comment: Ideas about what? The question is vague, it's not clear what version of Ubuntu you've installed, and what version you have now. Can you clarify that, and also post full hardware specs.

Comment: By "10.11", do you mean 11.10?

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Its a special version of ubuntu, 10.11 Tiny Typo. (j/k)

Answer (score 1):

When you boot up, press 'e' in the Grub menu to edit your boot options. Look for the part where it says "quiet splash." In the space right after that, type -nomodeset, then press Ctrl-x to boot up. If you can boot after that, before you log in, select Ubuntu2D (no effects) from the little cog menu by the login box. If it is a graphics driver issue, this will let you have a graphically limited desktop until you can install the proprietary drivers from "Additional Drivers." Once those are installed, you can try to see if Unity will work. Good Luck!